# Network graph with avatars as nodes

Tags: r, data-visualization, graph-theory

I've got a problem. I need to create network graph where avatars are nodes (different sizes). Similar to this one:

[image]

Furthermore on this image every avatar has the same size, what I need to do is different size of avatar depending on a chosen statistic (e.g. in-degree). I cannot find any tutorial in R, which explains how to do that.

Comment: Is it bad that I recognize some of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at NetworkX in Python, to add to the tremendous list of recommendations you're getting. I've found it to be quite flexible. It expressly allows things like images to be nodes:

> You might notice that nodes and edges are not specified as NetworkX objects. This leaves you free to use meaningful items as nodes and edges. The most common choices are numbers or strings, but a node can be any hashable object (except None), and an edge can be associated with any object x using

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/networkx-discuss/browse_thread/thread/aa11e38740863fc0) on their message list suggests people have been thinking about problems similar to yours, and I've found their community quite helpful.

If nothing else, NetworkX can absolutely calculate almost any graph measure you could care to think about, and lay out the graph for you using "avatar sized squares" which you could use to bring in the actual images.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the link, looks promising. Found a graph-architecture example similar to the OP's one: http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/ego_graph.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a [package](http://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/add.image.html) which allows you to add images in graphs.

You could arrange images along an [Archimedan spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) to make optimal use of the space you have in your network graph.

Then, all else you need is to add [lines](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/abline.html) to your plot in order to get something similar to what you have posted.

Comment: (+1) I like this hands-on-approach. Low-level, but if anything else fails ... ;)

Comment: Thank you mzuba for your answer. I have got more questions. What I need to do is to model something similar to this one:
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2701/4511843933_601b16ef1b.jpg
Is there a possibility to use one package for modeling graf and inserting avatars?

Comment: None that I know of, sorry. Furthermore, having lines not only between avatars and the middle of the graph, but also between avatars adds another layer of complexity to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/) template for Excel can do this. Unfortunately, my laptop is hosed and I cannot say that for sure. While it's not R, it's pretty easy to learn.

Comment: Hi, I am using NodeXl also, but I cannot import Avatars, maybe you know how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me where the data is from?

Comment: Note that NodeXL will also not work on a Mac.

Comment: For example, here's an example of a Twitter network graphed with NodeXL where the size of the node is proportional to the number of tweets ever made by that user: http://www.connectedaction.net/2009/10/01/twitter-flickr-networks-in-nodexl-version-95-lots-of-new-features-improved-performance/. Here's an example of how to add Twitter avatars: http://ideonexus.com/2011/01/17/social-network-mapping-fun-with-nodexl-and-science-online-2011/. If you need more help and have an academic affiliation, you may be able to get a free digital version of Analyzing Social Media Networks with NodeXL book.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these would help, but you might want to look at [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) or [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/). (Opensource, multiplatform tools, not R-based.) Or maybe [Tulip](http://tulip.labri.fr/TulipDrupal/).